# CSS Navigation with background images

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS navigation that looks like this:

```
        <div id="header_nav">
            <div class="header_nav_left"></div>
            <div class="header_nav_item"><span class="header_nav_item_span">Menu 1</span></div>
            <div class="header_nav_item"><span class="header_nav_item_span">Menu 2</span></div>
            <div class="header_nav_item"><span class="header_nav_item_span">Menu 3</span></div>
            <div class="header_nav_item"><span class="header_nav_item_span">Menu 4</span></div>
            <div class="header_nav_item"><span class="header_nav_item_span">Menu 5</span></div>
            <div class="header_nav_item"><span class="header_nav_item_span">Menu 6</span></div>
            <div class="header_nav_item"><span class="header_nav_item_span">Menu 7</span></div>
            <div class="header_nav_item_last"><span class="header_nav_item_span"></span></div>
            <div class="header_nav_right"></div>
        </div>
```

Visually the menu looks like this:

\ Menu 1 \ Menu 2 \ Menu 3 \ Menu 4 \ Menu 5 \ Menu 6 \ Menu 7 \

I am achieving the '\' effect through the use of a background image in each div.  The CSS for the menu follows:

```
.header_nav_left {
width:144px;
height:24px;
float:left;
background: url('/images/header_nav/left_cap.jpg') no-repeat;
background-position: right;
}

.header_nav_item {
height:24px;
font-size: 15px;
text-align:left;
float:left;
background: url('/images/header_nav/divider.jpg') no-repeat #fc7a06;
background-position: right;
min-width:75px;
}

.header_nav_item_span {
vertical-align:middle;
padding-left:5px;
}

.header_nav_item_last {
height:24px;
font-size: 15px;
float:left;
background:#fc7a06;
}

.header_nav_right {
height:24px;
float:left;
background: url('/images/header_nav/right_cap.jpg') no-repeat;
background-position: left;
min-width:24px;
}
```

The problem I am running into is that I have a control that automatically generates this menu based on the logged in user, and the text of the menu item varies.  The problem I am running into is that because I am using a background image and not an inline image, my menu inevitably winds up looking like this:

\ Menu \1 Menu 2\Men\u 3 Menu 4 \Menu 5\Menu 6 \ Menu 7 \

This makes sense: since the divider image isn't a block level image, the text within the span simply displays over top of it.  I can probably solve this problem by adding an inline image to each nav_item but I was hoping to keep the navigation as clean as possible.  Is there someway for me to apply a style that will take the divider image into account without needing to add the image inline?  If it matters the divider image is 24px wide.

Comment: try updating your images to somewhere and making a live demo showing the exact problem you have, or at least an image showing the problem is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way to do this is by placing right padding on the menu items and placing the background image within that padding area. E.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

#header_nav {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 144px;
    background: url('/images/header_nav/left_cap.jpg') no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#header_nav li {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 30px;
    background: #fc7a06 url('/images/header_nav/divider.jpg') no-repeat right;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 75px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="header_nav">
    <li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu 8</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Adding the padding was the correct approach.  Thanks!